# TYPO3 gzip compression

Tags: javascript, css, compression, gzip, typo3

I want to enable gzip-compression on my TYPO3 site. It's a shared hoster and I don't have access to the server configuration. This is what I've done so far:

- uncomment the TYPO3 .htaccess-file (the compression part)

  ```
  ### Begin: Compression via TYPO3 ###

  <FilesMatch "\.js\.gzip$">
      AddType "text/javascript" .gzip
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "\.css\.gzip$">
      AddType "text/css" .gzip
  </FilesMatch>

  AddEncoding gzip .gzip

  ## End: Compression via TYPO3 ###
  ```
- wrote this in my TYPO3 main-template

  ```
  config.compressJs = 1
  config.compressCss = 1
  ```
- localconf.php:

  ```
  $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['compressionLevel'] = '9'
  $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['compressionLevel'] = '9'
  ```

Google Pagespeed still points out, that i should compress my css and js. I don´t know why?
Here ist the Site: http://preview-list.lmenges.de/index.php?id=fahrschule

Thx for your help!

Comment: I had the same probem once, too - unsolved. Unrelated: Have you tried setting compressionLevel to a lower vaue, say 5? I experienced problems once with high values, esp. in the backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at mod_deflate: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css

Comment: Thank you! I solved this problem with the FAQ of my hoster STRATO. ii wrote this in my .htaccess-file:        mod_gzip_on Yes